# How to load an external image (generated on the fly) in Adobe Animate CC?

Tags: jquery, html, banner, animate-cc

**Problem**

I'm building an HTML5 banner with Adobe Animate CC (replaces Adobe Edge Animate).

I have to integrate an external GIF called via the following URL: "https://widgets.mobilenorth.eu/widgets/counter/0574PromoKidsFR".

It should start and end at a specific moment in the animation.

GIF size is 230(w)x83(h)

**What I did so far:**

I created a movie symbol named "counter" and placed a GIF in it from the library called "placeholder.gif".

My idea was to add code in the .js file to change the URL of the "placeholder.gif" which in the original code is called from the library.

Any other suggestion is welcome.

**.js file generated by Adobe Animate CC**

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 320,
    height: 250,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/placeholder.png?1466506297354", id:"placeholder"}
    ]
};



// symbols:



(lib.placeholder = function() {
    this.initialize(img.placeholder);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,230,83);


(lib.counter = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.instance = new lib.placeholder();

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,230,83);


// stage content:
(lib.flawithcounteras3_Canvas = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_24 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(24).call(this.frame_24).wait(1));

    // Layer 5
    this.instance = new lib.counter();
    this.instance.setTransform(44,79);
    this.instance._off = true;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(9).to({_off:false},0).wait(16));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = null;

})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

---

Any idea how I could change the URL of "placeholder.gif" from the Library to the gif generated by the URL "https://widgets.mobilenorth.eu/widgets/counter/0574PromoKidsFR" ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the widget URL? Since it doesn't have a path you will have to specify a type on it. `{type:"image"}`

Comment: We don't use an URL that ends with a .gif since the image is generated on the fly via the URL I mentioned. It's a count-down animated gif.

Comment: We changed the code and it works. Thank you for the tip:   manifest: [
        {src:"https://widgets.mobilenorth.eu/widgets/counter/0574PromoKidsFR", id:"placeholder", type:"image"}
    ]